# rails paperclip creating thumb image with smaller image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am using paperclip in rails to create different size images as follows

```
has_attached_file :upload,styles: { medium: ["500x300>",:jpg], thumb: ["150x100>",:jpg] }
```

Ill show my original image and also created thumbnail image here for better understanding

My original image is this

[image]

My thumb image created is

I am unable to understand what is happening but this works fine with large size images. What wrong happens here. How to correct it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [ImageMagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry):

> Use `>` to shrink an image *only* if its dimension(s) are **larger**
>   than the corresponding width and/or height arguments.

As a result, your original `256x256` image won't create your medium size, which defines `500x300`

I'm not sure if this has anything do with your problem, but I guess that the sizes and operators messed up something. I bet that playing around with other arguments, such as `!` and `^` will do.